# Evaluate the sum

Tags: performance, fortran, c, special-functions

I want to evaluate the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^k\cdot k^{-\alpha}$$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $\alpha\in[\frac{3}{4},1]$ with 8 digits accuracy.

If I am willing to expend up to a second of CPU time per calculation, how should I proceed?

Suppose I want a really fast scheme for the evaluation and I am willing to expend a lot of work. How should I proceed?

Any leads, clues or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, Qomo! Can you give us some background on what you have already done?

Comment: Also some context might be helpful.

Comment: @Deathbreath. I actually have no lead so far. Since this is a infinite series, then the series must converge at some point up to the digits of accuracy I want. I used the wolfram alpha, and I found the sum is actually called Polylogarithm. From Wikipedia, I found that I can change the sum to the integral of the Bose–Einstein distribution. However, I don't find anything that could help me solve it.

Comment: *"Since this is a infinite series, then the series must converge at some point [...]"* Uhm...that does not follow without some more conditions. Just looking at your series is I think it might, but I haven't proven it.

Comment: What you have is more commonly known as a [periodic zeta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.13), which, as you note, is a special case of the polylogarithm. If push comes to shove, you might be able to use a sequence transformation method on partial sums of the periodic zeta function for computational purposes.

Comment: Here: http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12 you can find an integral representation of the polylogarithm (formula 25.12.11). So rather than computing this directly as a sum, you can instead numerically evaluate an integral. For the integral given in DLMF, you can use Simpson's rule together with the substitution $x=e^{\pi \sinh t}$, and it should be accurate and fast ($t$ will have a small range, something like $(-4,4)$, for example).

Comment: @Kirill, if you're suggesting the *double-exponential* substitution, then there is no need to use Simpson's; the trapezoidal rule is sufficient for the transformed integral. See the papers of Takahasi and Mori for details.

Comment: @J.M. You're definitely right, I must have been confused. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 6):

What have you tried so far? This completely naive implementation manages to compute 7 (maybe 7.5) digits in 2.5 seconds on my laptop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main ()
{
  const double alpha = 1;
  std::cout.precision(16);

  std::complex<double> sum = 0;
  for (unsigned int k=1; k<10000000; ++k)
    {
      sum += std::pow(std::complex<double>(1,1)/std::sqrt(2.), k)
         *
         std::pow(k, -alpha);

      if (k % 1000000 == 0)
    std::cout << k << ' ' << sum << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Results are:

```
g/x> c++ -O3 x.cc
g/x> time ./a.out 
1000000 (0.2674004983680959,1.178096037989336)
2000000 (0.2674002483693692,1.17809664154278)
3000000 (0.2674001650362904,1.178096842727255)
4000000 (0.267400123369689,1.178096943319499)
5000000 (0.2674000983697316,1.178097003674927)
6000000 (0.2674000817030793,1.178097043911768)
7000000 (0.2674000697983399,1.178097072652377)
8000000 (0.2674000608697807,1.17809709420789)
9000000 (0.2674000539253223,1.178097110973249)

real    0m2.553s
user    0m2.548s
sys     0m0.001s
```

I'm certain this can be vastly improved, for example by using the fact that $(1+i)^k$ can only attain 8 different values that could be tabulated, that $\sqrt{2}^k$ can be computed very easily, etc. I have no doubt that with 20 minutes of work I could make this run in under one second for 8 digits. It might be harder to do for smaller values of $\alpha$, however, where convergence is slower.

Comment: You clearly get this, but ... *"using the fact that $(1+i)^k$ can only attain 8"*: The base there has non-unit length, it is the whole expression raised to the power $k$ that only takes on 8 values.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually $\left(frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^k$ that can only attain 8 different values.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question has a Fortran tag, here is Wolfgang's solution in Fortran:

```
implicit none
integer, parameter :: dp = kind(0.d0)
complex(dp), parameter :: i_ = (0, 1)

real(dp) :: alpha = 1
complex(dp) :: s = 0
integer :: k
do k = 1, 10000000
    s = s + ((i_+1)/sqrt(2._dp))**k * k**(-alpha)
    if (modulo(k, 1000000) == 0) print *, k, s
end do
end
```

Result are:

```
$ gfortran -O3 x.f90 
$ time ./a.out 
     1000000 ( 0.26740049836809593     ,  1.1780960379893362     )
     2000000 ( 0.26740024836936921     ,  1.1780966415427796     )
     3000000 ( 0.26740016503629038     ,  1.1780968427272547     )
     4000000 ( 0.26740012336968905     ,  1.1780969433194985     )
     5000000 ( 0.26740009836973161     ,  1.1780970036749265     )
     6000000 ( 0.26740008170307927     ,  1.1780970439117682     )
     7000000 ( 0.26740006979833991     ,  1.1780970726523770     )
     8000000 ( 0.26740006086978074     ,  1.1780970942078899     )
     9000000 ( 0.26740005392532235     ,  1.1780971109732488     )
    10000000 ( 0.26740004836978204     ,  1.1780971243856078     )

real    0m1.477s
user    0m1.472s
sys 0m0.000s
```

For comparison, on my computer the C++ code takes:

```
$ g++ -O3 x.cc
$ time ./a.out 
1000000 (0.2674004983680959,1.178096037989336)
2000000 (0.2674002483693692,1.17809664154278)
3000000 (0.2674001650362904,1.178096842727255)
4000000 (0.267400123369689,1.178096943319499)
5000000 (0.2674000983697316,1.178097003674927)
6000000 (0.2674000817030793,1.178097043911768)
7000000 (0.2674000697983399,1.178097072652377)
8000000 (0.2674000608697807,1.17809709420789)
9000000 (0.2674000539253223,1.178097110973249)

real    0m2.123s
user    0m2.116s
sys 0m0.004s
```

I use gcc 4.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The series is divergent for $\alpha < 1$.  Its convergence is suspicious using the ratio test.</strike>  For $\alpha = 1$, the sum is $-\log(1 - \sqrt{i})$, which is 0.2673999983697852 + 1.1780972450961725$i$, close to what is given in other answers.  Results from Mathematica.  By the way, $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ is $\sqrt{i}$, which also explains that its powers attain only 8 distinct values.

Comment: The series is not divergent, it is the definition of the polylogarithm.

Comment: You're correct. I believed Mathematica when it said "Sum::div: Sum does not converge." for $\alpha < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

mpmath has this

```
>>> import mpmath
>>> mpmath.polylog(1, (1+1j)/mpmath.sqrt(2))
mpc(real='0.26739999836978523', imag='1.1780972450961724')
>>> import numpy
>>> for x in numpy.linspace(0.75, 1.0, 11): print mpmath.polylog(x, mpmath.sqrt(1j))
... 
(0.13205298513153 + 1.22168160828646j)
(0.147070653672424 + 1.21783198879211j)
(0.161744021745461 + 1.21384547018142j)
(0.17607856182228 + 1.20973163332567j)
(0.190079791459314 + 1.20549967730407j)
(0.2037532636373 + 1.20115843051452j)
(0.217104557681381 + 1.19671636161604j)
(0.230139270736483 + 1.19218159029609j)
(0.242863009773464 + 1.18756189785626j)
(0.25528138410235 + 1.18286473761121j)
(0.267399998369785 + 1.17809724509617j)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plot the partial sums for the series, you get the following result:

[image]

This is the real part for $\alpha=0.91$ for partial sums of 10 to 100 terms. Clearly, there is a pattern here, and the imaginary part follows a similar pattern. It seems that you can probably take 8 successive partial sums and average them to get a much better approximation. Or at least you can get the asymptotic numeric behavior from these partial sums.

More analytically, you can break the sum into 8 separate sums over the different roots of unity:

$$ \sum_{j=1}^8 \left( \frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^j \sum_{k=0}^\infty (8k+j)^{-\alpha} $$

Each of the inner sums is a Hurwitz zeta function, for which there are special evaluation routines (like in [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Hurwitz-Zeta-Function.html)). Plotting out the sum in this way as a function of $\alpha$ gives

[image]

The blue line is the real part, red is the imaginary part. This seems pretty well behaved.